# How to obtain and click the URL of a dynamically loaded website?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the marathon results from the link (call it page A): https://www.marathon.tokyo/2023/result/index.php

Suppose I choose the 'Marathon Men' in the first option and then search, I get to the following webpage showing the results (call it page B):

[image]

When I click the names, I then get to the result of each individual athlete (page C):

[image]

My question is, how to get from page A to page C? I have no problems scraping the data I want from page C. The problem is getting from page A to B, obtain all the URLs pointing to the individual result entry (page C), and then navigate to page C.

To get from page A to page B, I have something like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.marathon.tokyo/2023/result/index.php'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

options = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "option")

for option in options:
    if 'Marathon Men' in option.text:
        print(option.text)
        option.click() # click on the option 100
        break
```

It does automatically select the correct option (Marathon Men), but I don't know how to click the 'search' button.

To get from page B to C, I try the following code while at page B:

```
raw_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a [@href]')
for link in raw_links:
    l = link.get_attribute("href")
    print("raw_link:{}".format(l))
```

And I get the following output:

```
raw_link:javascript:page(2);
raw_link:javascript:page(3);
raw_link:javascript:page(4);
# and so on
```

Again, the problem is I don't know how to convert those to clickable URLs and navigate to them.

Any help to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you from the initial page, search for Marathon Men, find the links to each runner's page, and print the text of the link. All you need to do is add your code to click the link and scrape the resulting runner's page that you said you already had.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

url = 'https://www.marathon.tokyo/2023/result/index.php'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "category")))).select_by_value("1")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btn_submit"))).click()

runners = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.mb10 td > a")))
for runner in runners:
    print(len(runners))
    print(runner.text)
```

Comment: I tried the code, but `runner.text` returns the text of the URL, which is the name of the athlete. How to actually navigate to the link? (and also go to page 2, 3 and so on of the result table)

Comment: ok I realized it's `runner.click()` to actually click the URL, and `driver.back()` to go back to the page showing 50 runners. But I still don't know how to go to the next page. Any help would be approciated.

Comment: This was just intended as an example to show you how to access each of the links on the page. If you want to click the link, just do `runner.click()` to go to the next page, scrape what you want, then `driver.back()` to return to the original page and repeat.